# All my queries fail

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would learn php (not the first time), I've installed mysql, apache, php and phpmyadmin (the first time, some hour ago, I've used easyphp but now all is installed manually to try to solve the problem).

So: all my queries fails. Also tried simple examples by the php manual like this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php (with my own connection data, who work fine) I've virtually all the privileges, with phpMyAdmin I do all I would. But when I code they fail ever.

As I said: connection work fine, I've all the privileges, code is copy-pasted by the manual :D But don't work. I use Windows 10 and all latest versions of Apache, MySQL, PHP, phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: also post your error message.

Comment: Have you seen some errors on screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the question. After an entire night triyng queries that don't run, a query is gone right. Sorry to all :D My installation was fine, i code bad (and the example i've linked don't run).

Comment: UPDATE: the trouble was another. I've noted that: if i insert (or other) data in a table that i've created with other query i can, with phpmyadmin not. Simply before i've never tried to create a table (with queries), only to insert/update/select. That's weird :D

Comment: Note: we don't close questions here, unless they are off-topic. The idea of this site is to preserve well-written questions and answers so they can benefit future readers.

Answer (score 0):

if your queries was failed here's some tips, (I assumed you're running windows 10 not windows server, you've installed apache, mysql, phpmyadmin on your own, and i don't know where you placed your php files, and i don't know your code)

1. Try uninstaling your apache, mysql and phpmyadmin, try installing xampp where you can download it for free [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)
2. You can use any editor, but some editor like PhpStorm need to configure your php compiler manually
3. If you're using editor like notepad or notepad++ make sure your files saved in htdocs (assuming you've run xampp) that can be found by default in C:/Xampp/htdocs/[anyfolder] than you can browse it via localhost/[anyfolder]
4. Or you can try another example from w3schools, it works fine for me

If you post your code it will very helping us to help solve your problem.